# how to change some listview item backcolor in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, c#-4.0

when we double click or do whatever how to change listview item `backcolor` or `foregcolor` in `WPF`? I want to do this one at run time.
also this code does not work

```
listview_name.SelectedItems[listview_name.SelectedIndex].Foreground=Brushes.Yellow;
```

please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/HiliteListViewItemsInWPF.aspx